# How to make the react video player responsive which is inside the iframe

Tags: reactjs, video, iframe, responsive, video-reactjs

I create one widget section(e.g. https://developers.zomato.com/widgets) which contain the video and have option to copy this widget code, so I copy the code and paste this code to any html page but for all screen size iframe video not responsive.

Comment: Can you show us the code how you render the widget?

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://css-tricks.com/responsive-iframes/
Visit https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/02/making-embedded-content-work-in-responsive-design/

You just need some knowledge to work this out. Learn some and it will help i promise.